# assigning an asynchronous function and its callback function to a single variable

Tags: javascript

After coming up with the function below, my next assignment is to make it loop every 3 seconds.

```
  Chat.fetch(function(x) // x is an array delivered by .fetch
    {
      for (var i = 0; i<x.length; i++)
        {
          Chat.display(x[i]); // and .display only takes strings as an argument
        }
    });
```

Now my first beginner's thought is to somehow get all the above into a single variable.

```
var myvariable = Chat.fetch(etc...
```

Then I would do something like

```
setInterval(myvariable, 3000);
```

Obviously that didn't work. What is it about that function that is stopping this approach?

Comment: You were close. `var myvariable = function(){ Chat.fetch(etc...) }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose a different solution.

```
// define the callback function
var displayMessages = function(x) // x is an array delivered by .fetch
    {
      for (var i = 0; i<x.length; i++)
        {
          Chat.display(x[i]); // and .display only takes strings as an argument
        }
      // Ivoke Chat.fetch with this callback again after 3 seconds
      setTimeout( function(){ Chat.fetch( displayMessages ); }, 3000 );
    } 
// start polling
Chat.fetch( displayMessages );
```

Now every time the callback is called it will shcedule `Chat.fetch` to fire again after 3 seconds after the previous messages have been rendered.

Comment: Thank you sir. I've seen that the pros seem to favor setTimeout, but is setInterval somehow flaky? I got it working just 10 seconds after your helpful hint.

Comment: `setInterval` may be less predictable. Server response time, network latency, script execution time come into play here. For example you fire `Chat.fetch`, the server chokes and it takes 5 seconds to process this particular request, but after 3 seconds you've fired `Chat.fetch` again and the response arrived instantly. Now you have the messages displayed in wrong order. Calling `setTimeout` from the callback guarantees that the next request is made after the previous has been processed.